# Structuring if statements properly

Tags: c, if-statement, statements

I'm in a intro to C programming class, and I'm working on a homework assignment. I just can't get to work properly. This is the homework assignment:

When someone buys a small number of widgets, they pay normal price. When someone buys
a medium number of widgets, Nick is quite happy, and gives them a discount off of the normal
price. When someone buys a large number of widgets, Nick falls in love with them, and gives
them an even bigger discount off of the normal price! But his problem is this: sometimes these
amounts are lower than his original costs, so he loses money on the sale!
For simplicity, we will assume that each widget costs Nick $0.40 each (so he should be selling
each of them for a higher cost than this to his customers):
`#define WIDGET_COST 0.40`

To help Nick save his business, please write a program that will prompt him for the price he
will sell each widget for, the percent he will discount medium purchases by, and the percent
he will discount large purchases by (each as whole numbers of a percent), then will output amessage indicating which of these choices is causing him not to make a profit. The possible
issues Nick could have are (output only the first in this list that is true):

1. Nick, your base price is too low!
2. Nick, you are discounting medium purchases too much!
3. Nick, you are discounting large purchases too much!

If there are no issues with his prices, you should just output:
All prices look good to me!
After outputting the appropriate message from above, don't forget to wish Nick good luck with
his new business:
Good luck!

This is my code so far:

```
int main(){

    double base;
    printf("How much are you selling each widget for?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &base);

    int medium;
    printf("How much are you discounting medium orders?\n");
    scanf("%d", &medium);

    int large;
    printf("How much are you discounting large orders?\n");
    scanf("%d", &large);

    double medium_total = base - medium/100 * base;
    double large_total = base - large/100 * base;

    if (base < WIDGET_COST) {
        printf("Nick, your base prices are to low!\n");
    }else if (medium_total < WIDGET_COST){
        printf("Nick, you are discounting medium purchases too much!\n");
    }else if (large_total < WIDGET_COST){
        printf("Nick, you are discounting large purchases too much!\n");
    }else {
        printf("All prices look good to me!\n");
    }

    printf("Good luck!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I believe it might be how I'm structuring the if statements: they won't output properly, either it will say base prices are too low or will say all prices are good, unless I discount over 100 on the purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
double medium_total = base - medium/100 * base;
```

with

```
double medium_total = base - medium/100.0 * base;
```

`medium` is an `int` which means that `medium / 100` is an integer division. By changing `100` to `100.0` a floating point division will be performed.

Same for `large_total` declaration.

Comment: That was it!!! Thanks so much! I cant believe a simple decimal point was all I needed! Haha, I obviously have a LOT to learn. But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `medium` being an `int`, `medium/100` is being performed as integer division, producing a `0` for `medium < 100`. That is why

> all prices are good, unless I discount over 100 on the purchases

To avoid, please use a cast,like

```
double medium_total = base - ((double)medium)/100 * base;
```

or write `100` as `100.0` to enforce a floating point division.

Similar case in `large/100` also.